# Blank white screen in OpenCart installation

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

My website http://www.redbullet.co.bw was working just fine last week Tuesday and I asked my web hosting company to install Zend Optimizer so that I can run some extra-service in site. He said he did add it, but when I update my database and add new directory everything got messed up.

I tried to sort it out but I failed. I then decided to uninstall everything and restore from my backup, but I still get a white blank page in my site, HTML pages can run no problem.

Even worse when I tried to install just a fresh copy of the latest opencart I still get a white blank page http://www.redbullet.co.bw/install/index.php. I checked error log and I get this:

```
[Wed Jul 18 18:04:18 2012] [error] [client 41.216.209.90] File does not exist: /var/www/xxx/web/favicon.ico
[Wed Jul 18 18:04:19 2012] [error] [client 41.216.209.90] File does not exist: /var/www/xxx/web/favicon.ico
[Wed Jul 18 18:04:19 2012] [error] [client 41.216.209.90] File does not exist: /var/www/xxx/web/favicon.ico
[Wed Jul 18 18:04:19 2012] [error] [client 41.216.209.90] File does not exist: /var/www/xxx/web/favicon.ico
[Wed Jul 18 18:04:20 2012] [error] [client 41.216.209.90] File does not exist: /var/www/xxx/web/favicon.ico
```

I don't think missing a favicon can result in a blank page, but looks like it can in my case and I am still getting the WHITE BLANK PAGE Error. Is it a problem in side or in my hosting company?

Comment: Have you considered enabling ERROR REPORTING?

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and temporarily `ini_set('display_errors',1);`

Comment: Ya, i tried that in index.php, still got a blank screen... the /install/index.php..., already has ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: the favicon has nothing to do with your script. Your browser is asking for the file and it is not there. if I go to your link page it gives me a 404 file not found error. Maybe you moved it. However, the error reporting is your clue here, and I suggest you place it high up in the file, before any executable code (including include directives).

Answer (score 2):

Although I am new in opencart, I also face this problem. Sometimes you see blank pages in opencart due to vqmod. Usually it is session error. You need to install a new fresh copy of VqMod whenever change your server. Also replace old index file with newly downloaded (uninstalled) copy of opencart.

Comment: is this mandatory?  I get a blank page on the domain root but the admin area works fine.  I noticed I have this vqmod but have no idea how to reinstall it, any ideas how I can do this please?

Answer (score 1):

I found my issue in the config.php files - the folders was incorrect. There is one in admin folder also that needs to be set...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it turns out that it doesn't like the database username being the same as the database name.